# chart.js with json data and jquery - error :-(

Tags: jquery, json, chart.js

I'm trying to visualize measurement data in json format.
View my current test on https://www.andreas-weller.de/visu/index.html. But unfortunately it simply doesn't work: on the console there's no error, but the chart is empty.

Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.getJSON('https://www.andreas-weller.de/visu/data.json', function(data) {

   var labels = data.chartData.data[0].map(function(e) {
      return e[0];
   });
   var data = data.chartData.data[0].map(function(e) {
      return e[1];
   });

   var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
         labels: labels,
         datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(129, 198, 2228)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 150, 215)',
            data: data
         }]
      },
      options: {
         responsive: 'true',
      }
   });
});

</script></body></html>
```

Comment: If you can please recreate it on codepen.  If there is a live version you will likely get to resolution more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your API you are receiving this object :

```
{
...,

  "data":[[1586736000000,0],[1586736900000,null]...]

...,
}
```

when you do this :

```js
var labels = data.chartData.data[0].map(...)
```

You are targeting the first array of data. Which is `[1586736000000,0]`.

So to fix your issue you can just do it like this:

```js
var labels = data.chartData.data.map(function(e) {
  return e[0];
});

var data = data.chartData.data.map(function(e) {
  return e[1];
});
```

`labels` will return : `[1586736000000,1586736900000,...]`

`data` will return : `[0,null,...]`

Also to not go through the same array twice you may prefer to use a forEach.